# Calculating contest winning chances

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

I recently took a final exam at my school that contained an interesting problem that I got wrong. Because it was a final exam, I didn't get any feedback on why it was wrong so I thought I'd post it here along with my approach so I can learn from it.

The problem was presented as follows:

> A trade fair has entries from $3$ competitors: $A$, $B$, $C$
>
> $A$ put in $15$ items, $4\%$ of $A$'s entries have won First prize.
> $B$ put in $5$ items, $6\%$ of $B$'s entries have won First prize.
> $C$ put in $10$ items, $3\%$ of $C$'s entries have won First prize.
>
> What is the chance that competitor $A$ will win First prize?

In interpreting the problem statement, I understood "$x\%$ of entries have won First prize" to mean "$x\%$ of entries have won First prize in the past." Also, I assumed that there is only one First prize awarded.

Using this interpretation, the only way I could think to approach it was to apply the definition of conditional probability to calculate the probability that $A$ wins the prize, given that a single prize is awarded to either $A$, $B$, or $C$.

I'll use the notation $P(X)$ to denote the probability that contestant $X$ wins, and $P(X_e)$ to represent the prior probability that a certain entry by contestant $X$ wins.

(**Edit:** As is pointed out in the accepted answer, the following is incorrect at the very least due to missing coefficients in each term of the numerator/denominator)

So, $P(A | A\lor B\lor C) =$

$\frac{P(A_e)*P(A_e')^{14}*P(B_e')^5*P(C_e')^{10}}{\left(P(A_e)*P(A_e')^{14}*P(B_e')^5*P(C_e')^{10}\right) + \left(P(A_e')^{15}*P(B_e)*P(B_e')^4*P(C_e')^{10}\right) + \left(P(A_e')^{15}*P(B_e')^5*P(C_e)*P(C_e')^{9}\right)} =$

$\frac{0.04*0.96^{14}*0.94^5*0.97^{10}}{\left(0.04*0.96^{14}*0.94^5*0.97^{10}\right) + \left(0.96^{15}*0.06*0.94^4*0.97^{10}\right) + \left(0.96^{15}*0.94^5*0.03*0.97^{9}\right)} \approx 0.30542$

In addition to finding where I went wrong, if anyone has tips for reasoning about problems like this so I can be more confident in my answers, I'd be very grateful.

As this is my first post, please let me know if I'm neglecting any of the rules and I'll fix it ASAP.

Thanks!

Comment: Do we know how often A, B, and C have submitted entries at the same competition in the past?  If not, I'm not sure we have enough information to proceed with the problem (even if we make certain qualifying assumptions).

Comment: @BrianTung No, the problem was stated exactly as quoted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a reasonable way to read the problem.  In your approach you missed a factor $15$ from $P(A|A \vee B \vee C)$ that comes from choosing which of $A$'s items wins and similarly for the other two.

My guess at what you were expected to do is to compute $P(A|A \vee B \vee C)=\frac {15\cdot 4\%}{15\cdot 4\%+5\cdot 6\% + 10\cdot 3\%}=50\%$ but I don't find that justified either.

Comment: +1.  I suspect you're right, based on the numbers working out cleanly, but that's bollocks.

Comment: I did consider that method, but I also couldn't think of how to justify it: the "expected wins" that each term appears to represent didn't seem to make sense in a contest with only one winning entry. However, I didn't notice that it evaluates to the nice round $50\%$, and with that knowledge I think there's a good chance that was what was intended. Thanks for pointing that out +1!

Comment: For the method I did choose, I don't quite see how adding those additional coefficients would be necessary, although it might well model a better interpretation. I treated each competitor's entry as being drawn with replacement from a pool of entries of which some were "winning" entries.

Comment: For example, if each competitor had $100$ possible entries in their pool, $A$, $B$, and $C$ would have $4$, $6$, and $3$ "winning" entries in their pools respectively. Then the probability that $A$ has the single "winning" entry in all the possible contests with exactly one "winning" entry would be $\frac{4*96^{14}*94^5*97^{10}}{4*96^{14}*94^5*97^{10} + 96^{15}*6*94^4*97^{10} + 96^{15}*94^5*3*97^{9}}$ which is equivalent to what I had above.

Comment: The obvious problem with my model is that the concept of a "winning" entry doesn't really make sense: intuitively given any entry, a better one should be able to beat it.

Comment: It seemed to me you were computing the chance A wins from a binomial distribution where A has one winning entry and $14$ non-winning entries.  That was the $0.04\cdot 0.96^{14}$.  There are $15$ choices for which entry is the winning one.  Your approach makes each person's chance of winning independent of the number of entries they submit.  You can cancel the $0.96^{14}$ and similar in your formula.

Comment: Oh, I understand now, thank you! I wasn't considering each entry separately and just assumed that symmetry took care of it. I'm pretty sure I've made this mistake before in counting problems. If I may ask, what makes you think that this corrected version isn't the intended answer?

Comment: I can't explain the logic that gets from the supplied information to either of our equations.  My approach is simpler, but I have no confidence I am reading the problem setter's mind correctly